# How to automatically declare routes in Angular.js when using Express.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, dry

I'm building an Express.js and Angular.js application. I'm noticing as I add views and controllers to Angular.js that I'm duplicating work. I'm actually declaring the route in two places. It doesn't seem very DRY.

Here I'm adding the route in Express:

```
app.get('/api/admin', admin.root(req, res));
```

And my Angular configuration:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.filters', 'myApp.services', 'myApp.directives']).
  config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) 
    {
      $routeProvider.when('/api/admin', {templateUrl: 'admin', controller: AdminCtrl});
      $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

My question is, is there any way to not have to declare each route in the angular.module function? Maybe automatically generate this?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a fullfront-end framework, it doesn't need expressJS to handle views.

The expressJS part should be the only the "back-end" part, that produces an API (usually a RESTful API). AngularJS then is the client of this API.

The AngularJS router and the API are then two different things, so there is no duplication, even the the routes names the same.